# Optimize database design

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with users deposits in different currencies (they are not real, just for example):

```
|user_id|amount|datetime|currency_type|
---------------------------------------
|      1|   200|2020-etc|          eur|
|      2|   150|2020-etc|          usd|
|      1|   150|2020-etc|          usd|
```

To calculate user total deposit i do:

```sql
select currency_type, sum(amount) from deposits d where user_id = 1 group by currency_type;
```

^ result:

```
|currency_type|sum|
-------------------
|          eur|200|
|          usd|150|
```

Lets imagine that amount of records in this table constantly growing (and currency_types can be hundreds). Calculation will take more and more time. So my approach is use separate tables with closing deposit balance for each asset type.

**deposit_statements** table (1 record for each user monthly)

```
|deposit_statement_id| date| user_id|
-------------------------------------
|                   1| ....|       1|
```

**statements** table (composite PK deposit_statement_id + currency_type)

```
|deposit_statement_id| date| closing_deposit_balance|currency_type|
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   1| ....|                     200|          eur|
|                   1| ....|                     150|          usd|
```

Then i theoretically take last month record from **deposit_statements** and sum all closing balances (for each currency respectively) with sum of all
deposits from **deposits** table which date is bigger than date in **deposit_statements**. P.S. if someone could write this query for me it would nice.

Is there a better approach for this problem?

2nd possible solution (partitioning):

What if throw **deposit_statements** completely and add **user_id** in statements table and partition it by a month?

Comment: Looks like a good solution. With proper indexes the query should be fast. Nevertheless, creating a "table with closing deposit balance" is **redundancy**. You need to manage redundancy appropriately to avoid inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend a half-way solution.  First, you should wait until you have a performance problem.  You might be pleasantly surprised and on a large database, you can still add up 100 values in a reasonable amount of time.

Then, if you decide that you really do need the current balance, add a column to the `user_id` table.  Initialize the value with the current balance.  Then use triggers to maintain the value.

Splitting the values into "statements" and "more recent" values sounds like a complication of queries.  It also runs the risk that a historical adjustment will throw things out-of-whack.

I'm not generally a fan of triggers.  But if the goal is to have a current balance that is readily available and accurate, then they sound like the better solution.

Comment: Ty for your answer. No, deposit table is simplified for the answer. Balance always going to be calculated as sum of debits - sum of credits. So there is no "balance" field. There would be millions of transactions. So count from all table with millions of entries is not a good idea i believe. So i have this closing_balance once a month as a starting point.

Comment: And there never going to be historical adjustment. They are like audit tables

Comment: what about partitioning? If i throw **deposit_statements** completely, add **user_id** in **statements table** and partition it by a month?

Comment: @xxx_coder_noscope . . . Either you need the balance right away or you don't.  I don't see much advantage to having "incremental" "statements", when you can just solve the entire problem.  But it is your database and your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is a better approach.

I would have designed a system like this with 2 tables - one table to store the transactions (the real fact of adding money **to** the account vs withdrawing money **from** the account) and another table to store the account balance during relevant time intervals. We can always rebuild the history from the transactions table (it is the primary source of truth) - but this historic table provides us with precomputed values for any given point in time.

So the transactions table may have the following structure

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| id            | Serial          |
+---------------+-----------------+
| created       | TimeStampTZ     |
+---------------+-----------------+
| is_withdrawal | Boolean         | (we can get rid of this flag if you allow negative numbers for the amount)
+---------------+-----------------+
| currency_id   | Integer         |
+---------------+-----------------+
| amount        | DoublePrecision |
+---------------+-----------------+
| account_id    | Integer         |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

And the history table may have the following structure

```
+-------------+-----------------+
| account_id  | Integer         |
+-------------+-----------------+
| currency_id | Integer         |
+-------------+-----------------+
| balance     | DoublePrecision |
+-------------+-----------------+
| valid_from  | TimeStampTZ     |
+-------------+-----------------+
| valid_until | TimeStampTZ     |
+-------------+-----------------+
```

And if you want - you can maintain a cached value for the current (latest) balance in a 3rd table

```
+-----------------+-----------------+
| account_id      | Integer         |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| currency_id     | Integer         |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| current_balance | DoublePrecision |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```